# Must switch the same iframe twice to get inside the iframe IE

Tags: c#, iframe, selenium, webdriver

My application must be used in IE. I am automating test in which the script will do the following in listed order

- select option 'Accounting' in drop-box "Category" to get Accounting-associated options displayed in drop-box "Category"
- select option 'Payment" in drop-box "Name" for page 'Accounting Payment Filter' to display
- verify that the 'Employee' text-box in this page is visible

HTML source BEFORE option 'Payment' is selected (the page 'Accounting Payment Filter' has not displayed):

```
<form id="Main">
    <span id="Entity">
    <div>
       <select id="drop_Category">
         <option value =""/>
         <option value = "Accounting">           
       <select id="drop_Name"> <-!
         <option value =""/>
         <option value ="Payment">
```

HTML source AFTER option 'Payment' is selected (page 'Accounting Payment Filter' displays and there is an iframe)

```
<form id="Main">
    <span id="Entity">
    <div class="ig_Control">
         <div class ="ig_content">
             <iframe title ="javascript:''">
                 <html>
                   <body>
                      <form id="Form1">
                         <div id="Panel1">
                             <table id="table1"
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                       <input id="Employee">

    <div>
       <select id="drop_Category">
         <option value =""/>
         <option value = "Accounting">           
       <select id="drop_Name"> <-!
         <option value =""/>
         <option value ="Payment">
```

I have the code up to 'Payment' option is selected. Now I call SwitchIframe function, then find and verify the text-box:

```
public static bool IsTextboxVisible (IWebDriver driver, Dictionary of all needed data )
{
     //....
     //Call to switch into iframe
     SwitchIFrame(driver,stringXPath);

     //Verify text-box is visible
     var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
     //Script crashes here- can't find element
     var Textbox = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(TexboxID))); 
     return Textbox.Displayed;
}

public static void SwitchIFrame (IWebDriver driver,string strXPath)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
    var iFrame = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath(strXPath)));
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrame);
}
```

Script can't find the text-box even when I increase the waiting time. Then I tried finding the ID "drop_Name" instead, and the script can find that drop-box. That means it did not switch into the iframe. So I switch that SAME iframe one more time:

```
public static bool IsTextboxVisible (IWebDriver driver, Dictionary of all needed data )
{
     //....
     //Call to switch into iframe
     SwitchIFrame(driver,stringXPath);
     //Call again to switch into the same iframe 
     SwitchIFrame(driver,stringXPath);

     //Verify text-box is visible
     var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); 
     //Script crashes here- can't find element
     var Textbox = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id(TexboxID))); 
     return Textbox.Displayed;
}
```

Now script can find the text-box though sometimes is still given the exception that the XPath cannot be evaluated or not results in a web element. I update function SwitchIFrame:

```
public static void SwitchIFrame (IWebDriver driver,string strXPath)
{
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
    try
    {
      var iFrame = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath(strXPath)));
      driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrame);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFrameException)
    {
       var iFrame = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath(strXPath)));
       driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrame);
    }
}
```

But the same exception still happens sometimes in the 'try...' block. My questions:

- Why do I have to switch the same iframe twice to get inside one iframe?
- Why didn't 'try...catch...' in SwitchIframe function catch the
  exception?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to switch around the order of events a little bit.  Based on the code you have I would actually wait on those additional divs that are loaded after the selection to become visible.

```
public static bool IsTextboxVisible (IWebDriver driver, Dictionary of all needed data )
{    
 //Verify text-box is visible
  var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 

  var Textbox = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.ClassName("ig_content")));

  SwitchIFrame(driver,stringXPath);
  return Textbox.Displayed;
}

public static void SwitchIFrame (IWebDriver driver,string strXPath)
{
    //var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
    var iFrame = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(strXPath));
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame(iFrame);
}
```

The reason for the change of order is that those divs are connected to the original html document. Assuming those divs appear when the iFrame is loaded you should be the able to switch to the new iFrame document.   If your xPath does not work (IE may or may not play well with it) I would try using the index position of the frame in the switch to.  This might be more reliable since the frame does not have an id to find.

> driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);

I removed the wait from the switch statement because in this case if the iFrame is dependent on the divs loading all you should need to do is have the divs there and the frame is loaded a long with it.